# Time-varying biquad state persistence, MATLAB DSP objects

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing

I'm running time-varying biquads on an input of audio, but am having dropouts at the boundaries of every block. The reason for this is clear: the state variables (x1,x2,y1,y2) are resetting when step() is called.

I have a home-rolled M-file to run the biquads() that accepts and returns an array with the states of x1,x2,y1,y2. It works, but processing 30 seconds of audio takes 700 seconds.

When I switch to the DSP system objects, the runtime cuts to 90 seconds, except the state of the filter resets at the processing block boundaries. I tried using the `persistent` keyword but the regular glitches are still there. Any ideas? The help file does not point to any way of dealing with this other than filtering the entire file at once, which is not practical because the coefficients of the bank of filters will change between calls to `step()`. Thanks for any help.

```html
% create bank of biquads
persistent biquad;

if isempty(biquad)
    biquad = dsp.BiquadFilter();
end

persistent biQ1;
persistent biQ2;
persistent biQ3;

if isempty(biQ1)
    biQ1 = dsp.BiquadFilter();
end
if isempty(biQ2)
    biQ2 = dsp.BiquadFilter();
end
if isempty(biQ3)
    biQ3 = dsp.BiquadFilter();
end

for i = 1 : numBlocks  
    
    if coeffChange == 1
        % calculate the filter coefficient
        release(biQ{1});
        release(biQ{2});
        release(biQ{3});
        biQ{1}.SOSMatrix = cookEQ(fs,smoothF0(i),-60,10,'peak');
        biQ{2}.SOSMatrix = cookEQ(fs,2*smoothF0(i),-60,10,'peak');
        biQ{3}.SOSMatrix = cookEQ(fs,3*smoothF0(i),-60,10,'peak');
    end
   
    % first one acts on original input, then done in series
    release(biQ{1});
    output((i-1)*overlap+1:i*overlap) = step(biQ{1},x((i-1)*overlap+1:i*overlap));
   for j = 2 : 3
       release(biQ{j});
       output((i-1)*overlap+1:i*overlap) = step(biQ{j},output((i-1)*overlap+1:i*overlap));
   end
 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to avoid boundary problems between biquad processing blocks is to have each block output its final state variables (x1,x2,y1,y2) as well as the processed audio vector, save those variables somewhere, and then pass those variables back to the next block as additional input parameters to use for initialization of the block process.

But note that these state inputs might not be the correct ones if the biquad has changed filter coefficients.  You might need to do something like cross-fading the outputs of overlapped processing blocks when they are using differing filter parameters.

Comment: Thanks hotpaw, i ended up using the `filter()` command's flag to output the states and I get a smooth output without discontinuities. The cross-fade is a good tip, that might make the transitions even smoother.